# Parse JSON document into table

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on parsing JSON document with an object array into a SQL Server table. I'm stuck with how to parse the complex object array.

I tried `subproject.id` and that did not work. I usually use the below code to parse a JSON array which works just fine but in this case it does not.

JSON:

```
{
    "Data": [        
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "date": "2020-01-20",
            "subproject": [
                {
                    "id": "123",
                    "projectname": "new1",
                    "refnum": "123:new1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "456",
                    "projectname": "new2",
                    "refnum": "456:new2"
                }
            ],
            "projectid": "1234",
            "projectdate": "2020-01-27"
        },
        {
            "name": "DEF",
            "date": "2020-01-30",
            "subproject": [
                {
                    "id": "789",
                    "projectname": "new3",
                    "refnum": "789:new3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "901",
                    "projectname": "new4",
                    "refnum": "901:new4"
                }
            ],
            "projectid": "4567",
            "projectdate": "2020-02-07"
        }
    ]
}
```

SQL:

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:/data/project.json', SINGLE_CLOB) X

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH (
     [name] NVARCHAR(256),
     [date] DATE,
     [projectid] INT,
     [projectdate] DATE
     )
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Seems like you're skipping over the `subproject` property. Have you read the [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) documentation yet? It explains how to use `AS JSON` to extract nested data, which can then be used with `JSON_QUERY()`, `JSON_VALUE()` or `OPENJSON()` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `AS JSON` clause in the first `OPENJSON()` call (to specify that the `$.subproject` property contains an inner JSON array) and a combination of another `OPENJSON()` call and `APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.Data') WITH (
   [name] NVARCHAR(256),
   [date] DATE,
   [projectid] INT,
   [projectdate] DATE,
   [subproject] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.subproject' AS JSON  
) j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (j1.[subproject]) WITH (
   [subprojectid] INT '$.id',
   [subprojectname] NVARCHAR(256) '$.projectname',
   [subprojectrefnum] NVARCHAR(256) '$.refnum'
) j2
```